# LLaMA2 Workload Traces

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, transformer-model, large-language-model, huggingface

Is there any dataset that captures the execution patterns and resource consumption for each layer of the LLaMA2 model? My research requires the analysis of granular workload traces, focusing particularly on metrics like TFLOPS, GPU memory usage, memory bandwidth, storage demands, and runtime needs for various components of the LLaMA2 model.  I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on where to find this type of data. Thank you in advance.